# Bat файл, который открывает html в специальном окне

Tags: bat

Здравствуйте! На днях столкнулся с такой проблемой - мне нужно сделать bat-файл, который будет открывать html-файл в окне, но главное окно не браузера. Как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я понял, что сделать bat-файл, который будет исполнять данную задачу, будет сложно (если это вообще возможно). В момент открытия вопроса я был плох в сфере создания настольных приложений, и думал, что `batch` и вообще любая `shell` умеют все на свете, и в том числе запускать веб-сайты в окне без каких либо сторонних программ или библиотек.

Хорошим вариантом для создания desktop-приложений будет фреймворк `Electron.js` или `NW.js` для `Node.js`. Я использую `Electron.js`, потому что по нему больше документации и уроков.

Если использовать `C#`, который является одним из главных языков программирования для `Windows`, то там, как минимум, есть компонент что-то типа `WebView` (не помню, как точно называется), который работает на движке `Internet Explorer`, если я не ошибаюсь.

Если вы, как и я, не хотите `Internet Explorer` для современной программы, то для `C#` есть библиотеки, которые внедряют компонент `WebView`, работающий на движке `Chromium` от `Google`.

Спасибо всем, кто пытался мне помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так (имя программы и файла поменять на реальные, программу дописать, чтобы открывала файл, переданный аргументом):

```
start "" some-program.exe file.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Как то так

```
explorer %путь%\index.html
```

запустит дефолтный браузер

Comment: Из вопроса: _"окно не браузера"_

Comment: @Qwertiy, а тут и не браузер. Тут проводник. правда, проводник откроет файл дефолтным приложением для данного типа. Я, кстати, вообще не понял эту часть вопроса. Может должно было быть "не главное окно браузера"? )

Comment: @iRumba, я понял, что ему надо открыть в конкретной программе, которая вообще браузером не является, тем более, дефаултным.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну так поэтому данный ответ вполне корректен. Измени explorer на notepad или на что душе угодно и будет счастье. Автор вопроса же не указал конкретное ПО

Comment: @iRumba, ну если с этой стороны смотреть... Но вообще ответ по то, как в дефаултном браузере открыть - что explorer его сам определит и запустит.

Comment: Честно говоря пропустил вчера "но главное окно не браузера", но предложенный мной вариант по большому счету запускает не именно браузер, а приложение которое по умолчанию ассоциированно для открытия файлов с указанным расширением. То есть для решения задачи автора нужно либо ассоциировать .html с требуемым приложением, либо если это по каким либо причинам делать нельзя, то вместо explorer указывать путь к требуемому приложению